# How can I send a signal without the shell waiting for the currently running program to finish?

Tags: shell, sh, signals

If I send a signal using kill, it seems to wait until the current program (in this example `sleep 1000`) finishes running. When I instead send SIGINT via pressing `Ctrl+C` in the shell, it receives the interrupt immediately however.

What I want, however, is for the interrupt to be received immediately after sending the signal via `kill`. Also, why does it behave like I would want it to when I press `Ctrl+C`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
int_after_a_while() {
    local pid=$1
    sleep 2
    echo "Attempting to kill $pid with SIGINT"
    # Here I want to kill the process immediately, but it waits until sleep finishes
    kill -s INT $pid
}

trap "echo Interrupt received!" INT
int_after_a_while $$ &
sleep 1000
```

I would appreciate any help on this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you using as your `kill` command? Are you referring to the `kill` command you have at the end of `int_after_a_while()`?

Comment: Yes, sorry if that wasn't clear from the original question.

Comment: I think your answer is here (I don't want to steal someone else's credit by giving my own answer): https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/282631/392334

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the referenced answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282525/why-did-my-trap-not-trigger/282631#282631 the shell will normally wait for a utility to complete before running a trap. Some alternatives are:

- Start the long running process in the background, then wait for it using the `wait` builtin. When a trapped signal is received during such a wait, the wait is interrupted and the trap is taken. Unfortunately, the exit status of `wait` does not distinguish between the child process exiting on a signal and a trap occurring. For example

```sh
    sleep 1000 &
    p=$!
    wait "$p"
```

- Send a signal to the whole process group via `kill -s INT 0`. The effect is much like if the user had pressed Ctrl+C, but may be more extreme than you want if your script is run from another script.
- Use a shell such as zsh or FreeBSD sh that supports `set -o trapsasync` which allows running traps while waiting for a foreground job.